# PHP and Smarty: filemtime(): stat failed

Tags: php, smarty

I am getting the following error `filemtime(): stat failed`.

The full error is:

> ERRNO: 2 TEXT: filemtime(): stat failed for
>   C:\hatshop/presentation//templates_c\74b952bedd7366ad261e8be04bc5be8ef15c2fc1.file.departments_list.tpl.php
>   LOCATION: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_resource.php, line
>   720, at March 30, 2013, 12:14 am Showing backtrace:
>   filemtime("C:\hatshop/presentation//templates_c\74b952bedd7366ad261e8be04bc...")
>   # line  720, file: C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_resource.php
>   Smarty_Template_Source.getCompiled(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) #
>   line  654, file:
>   C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php
>   Smarty_Internal_Template.__get("compiled") # line  154, file:
>   C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase.fetch(null, null, null, null, false,
>   false, true) # line  286, file:
>   C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php
>   Smarty_Internal_Template.getSubTemplate("departments_list.tpl", null,
>   null, null, null, Array[0], "0") # line   34, file:
>   C:\hatshop\presentation\templates_c\3522bf5c12e26ac546fbfc3693da6da22f71f1d6.file.index.tpl.php
>   content_5155dc5df33599_26514511(Object: Smarty_Internal_Template) #
>   line  180, file:
>   C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase.fetch("index.tpl", null, null, null,
>   true) # line  374, file:
>   C:\hatshop\libs\smarty\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase.display("index.tpl") # line    7, file:
>   C:\hatshop\index.php

I have read many posts on this problem but most of them
are not clear how to apply the solution, they just suggest things in
a very unclear way.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same error solved it by adding:

```
$this->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
$this->muteExpectedErrors();
```

to my application.php

```
<?php

// Reference Smarty library
require_once SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php';

/* Class that extends Smarty, used to process and display Smarty
  files */

class Application extends Smarty {

    // Class constructor
    public function __construct() {
        // Call Smarty's constructor
        parent::__construct();

       $this->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
       $this->muteExpectedErrors();

        // Change the default template directories
        $this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_DIR;
        $this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
        $this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
        $this->addPluginsDir(SMARTY_DIR . 'plugins');
        $this->addPluginsDir(PRESENTATION_DIR . 'smarty_plugins');
    }

}

?>
```

do check this link:

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21352&sid=88c6bbab5fb1fd84d3e4f18857d3d10e

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this kind of error , I think it is related to file permission set in the smarty folders like template_c . Because Smarty to try to determine if we can use the Cached file or not and try to get the file Time. Please check your process is having correct set of permission on the folders

Answer (score 0):

This happens when registered stream wrapper class has no defined `url_stat` method. It's unclear in the documentation but this method is required by PHP stat cache.