# Filemtime function - “stat failed for” addresses.css

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I already read it so many questions and answers about it but I can't still solve my problem...

```
 "11 Jan 2017 01:04:26","/var/www/html/sf_prestashop/shop/classes/Media.php:
    229",

"**(Warning) filemtime(): stat failed for** /var/www/html/sf_prestashop/shop/themes/theme-sciencefirst/css/**addresses.css**"

"11 Jan 2017 01:04:26","/var/www/html/sf_prestashop/shop/classes/Media.php:
229",

"(Warning) filemtime(): stat failed for /var/www/html/sf_prestashop/shop/modules/blockpaymentlogo/**blockpaymentlogo.css"**

"11 Jan 2017 01:04:26","/var/www/html/sf_prestashop/shop/classes/Media.php:
229",

"(Warning) filemtime(): stat failed for /var/www/html/sf_prestashop/shop/modules/blockmyaccount/**blockmyaccount.css"**
```

How to resolve this warning?

Comment: This is most probably a permission problem. Make sure the user owning and running your httpd server process has the correct permissions to the folder `/var/www/html/sf_prestashop/`.. If not, issue the command `chown httpd.httpd /var/www/html/sf_prestashop/ -R` or of course `nginx.nginx` if you run that. 
[Fixing Prestashop Permissions](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/200692-777-755-and-644-problem-with-chmod-permissions-im-begging-for-help-please/)

Comment: Please check following URL for the solution to your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639292/filemtime-function-filemtime-stat-failed-for-filenames-with-umlauts

Also, check https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/200692-777-755-and-644-problem-with-chmod-permissions-im-begging-for-help-please/

Comment: Please take a look at the following URL, it might help you in fixing this issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713414/php-and-smarty-filemtime-stat-failed